# How to find the x value (coordinate) corresponding to some y value? (OxyPlot)

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, oxyplot

I'm using OxyPlot in C# to plot a chart based on a finite set of data points, not a function. The resultant chart from OxyPlot has a smooth, continuous curve covering the whole range of points.

My goal is that, given some value y, find the corresponding x value. I want to do that by utilizing the chart plotted with OxyPlot. Are there any straightforward ways (perhaps using some OxyPlot features) to do that?

Note: The y value is determined in the back-end based on some calculations——it's not from the user. The few resources I found online suggested using a mouse click event, but unfortunately that wouldn't work for my case.

Comment: The base class Series has a virtual function GetNearestPoint() - could that be what you need?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JimFoye The GetNearestPoint() function takes a ScreenPoint as an argument. I'm not sure if it'll be possible for me to know the ScreenPoint from the back-end, since it'll vary based on the application window.

Comment: I think what you need to do is look at the OxyPlot source and see how the tracker calls GetNearestPoint(). It must be starting with a mouse position and then converting it relative to the plot view, or else GetNearestPoint() does that - but it should be possible to figure out what the tracker is doing, since you want to do the same thing (if I understand your question correctly).

Comment: @JimFoye This sounds like a reasonable idea. I'll dig into the source code and see how GetNearestPoint() is used. Thank you!

Comment: hope this helps .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54079198/7299782